# Defining SqlCommand.CommandTimeout from the config file

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I need to set `CommandTimeout` property for a particular `SqlCommand`. The premise is that, the main connection string and `SqlConnection` being used cannot be changed. I like to make defining the timeout value configurable. Wanted to know if its good and fair practice to define it in the app.config (it's a desktop app)?

Comment: A bit of a subjective question, but I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: But do you want to change the Timeout for every SqlCommand used in your application or just for a single command?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Rather than an absolute problem its just a conundrum for me and wanted to know the best possible way to tackle it :)

Comment: @Steve For just a single SqlCommand and not for all the commands in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app.config` is a fantastic place for that type of setting. Maybe something like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="commandTimeout" value="2" />
</appSettings>
```

and that would then be in some perspective duration based on how you leverage it. Maybe something like this:

```
var timeout = cnn.ConnectionTimeout;
var configTimeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["commandTimeout"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configTimeout))
{
    timeout = Convert.ToInt32(configTimeout);
}
```

That could of course exist in a static class, like this maybe:

```
public static class AppSettings
{
    private static int _commandTimeout = -1;
    public static int CommandTimeout
    {
        get
        {
            if (_commandTimeout != -1) { return _commandTimeout; }

            var configTimeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["commandTimeout"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configTimeout))
            {
                _commandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(configTimeout);
            }
            else
            {
                _commandTimeout = 1; // this is the default if the setting doesn't exist
            }

            return _commandTimeout;
        }
    }
}
```

Then all you'd have to do is:

```
var timeout = AppSettings.CommandTimeout;
```

or even more concisely:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = AppSettings.CommandTimeout;
```

Comment: Default timeout for SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property is 30 seconds :)

Comment: @rageit, that's true, I was just throwing numbers into my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CommandTimeout property and a Time Paramater in the application config file.

```
connection = Factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.ConnectionString;
connection.Open();

this.cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeConfigParam"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extend @mike-perrenoud's answer with using TimeSpan as type for the AppConfig option value. It is more readable and understandable for further adjustments.
The option could be added via `Project Properties` -> `Settings tab`. So that the code would like

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandTimeout = (int)Properties.Settings.Default.SqlCommandTimeout.TotalSeconds;
```

app.config

```
<setting name="SqlCommandTimeout" serializeAs="String">
  <value>00:05:00</value>
</setting>
```

Properties/Settings.settings

```
// generated by VS
<Setting Name="SqlCommandTimeout" Type="System.TimeSpan" Scope="Application">
  <Value Profile="(Default)">00:05:00</Value>
</Setting>
```

Properties/Settings.Designer.cs

```
// generated by VS
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("00:05:00")]
public global::System.TimeSpan SqlCommandTimeout {
  get {
    return ((global::System.TimeSpan)(this["SqlCommandTimeout"]));
  }
 }
```